# How to change the text color in a disabled edit box using MFC?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, cedit

I have a dialog in which the edit box is disabled but the text should be displayed in red instead of the default grey. I tried the following:

```
void CMyEdit::OnEnable(BOOL bEnable)
{
  CEdit::OnEnable(bEnable);

  if (bEnable)
  {
    m_BackGroundColor = kRGBWhite;
  }
  else
  {
    m_BackGroundColor = kRGBDefaultGray;
  }

  m_TextColor = kRGBRed;
  m_BackgroundBrush.DeleteObject();
  m_BackgroundBrush.CreateSolidBrush(m_BackGroundColor);

  Invalidate();
}
```

But its still displaying the text in grey only. But if I remove the base class call `CEdit::OnEnable(bEnable);` then new text color takes effect. Can anyone explain whats wrong in the code?

Thanks for your time.

cheers...

**EDIT:** (*Moving my comment to an edit*) Sorry I forgot to mention it in my original post. Instead of handling the ON_WM_CTLCOLOR(), ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT() is handled. What I don't understand is that removing the call to the base class, changes the color of the text to what's specified but keeping it changes it only to the default grey.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN: An edit control that is **not read-only or disabled** sends the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn.

The corollary is there is no way to change the background or text color of a disabled (or readonly) edit box, besides subclassing it and do the painting yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please see the comment I added to the question.

Comment: I think read-only edits also send the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message; I use readonly edits instead of disabled in order to control the coloring of them while readonly because of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle [OnCtlColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwk06hc(VS.80).aspx) handler and in your message map put this `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()`

```
afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
 //logic here, change pDC as needed, return brush to use
}
```